# How to set Fortran Integer kind

Tags: fortran, fortran95

```
program PEU3
integer(kind=7) :: num = 600851475143
integer(kind=7) :: pf, counter
```

This is a section of my fortran code. Num is very large, so I tried to set it to kind = 7, but for some reason It's still throwing Error 217 - Integer(Kind=3) Constant out of range, for the line declaring num, even though I've declared that num ought to be kind 7. I've been at it for a while and can't understand for the life of me why it wouldn't be working. Help would be *greatly* appreciated. My IDE is Plato, with silverfrost compiler, if it's relevant.

Comment: With  hard-wired `kind=7` you are guaranteed that you ode will not compile by almost any other compiler. Please don't use magic constants for kind numbers see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/838310/fortran-90-kind-parameter

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Notice how the error is "**Constant** out of range", not "*Variable* out of range". The Constant in the line

```
integer(kind=7) :: num = 600851475143
```

is the actual number: 600851475143. By default, your compiler seems to want to store constants as 32 bit integers, and that number is too large for that.

The simplest solution would be to tell the compiler to store that constant as the same kind as the `num`, so something along these lines:

```
integer(kind=7) :: num = 600851475143_7
```

That trailing underscore tells the compiler to store the constant as an integer of kind 7.

**BUT**

I need to point out that what number corresponds to which kind is compiler and machine dependent. Which means like that, the code would not be easily transferable.

So please use one of these constructs:

For newer compilers (Fortran 2008 compliant), use the intrinsic `iso_fortran_env` module:

```
program PEU3
    use iso_fortran_env, only: int64
    implicit none
    integer(kind=int64) :: num = 600851475143_int64
```

For older compilers, you can use the `selected_int_kind` method to find out the best integer kind. It takes a single parameter: The maximum number of (base 10) digits to store. (Though technically, if you pass it the number 12, it would only guarantee the numbers between `-10^12 ... 10^12`, so you'd have to pass 13 to be certain that your number can be stored.)

```
integer, parameter :: largeint = selected_int_kind(13)
integer(kind=largeint) :: num = 600851475143_largeint
```

Both of these methods are more easily readable and compiler-independent, so much easier to port to a new system.

Comment: I typed in this: integer, parameter :: my_kind = selected_int_kind(13)
integer(kind = my_kind) :: pf, counter, st
pf = 0
num = 600851475143, however I'm still getting the same error: 217 to the line assigning num

Comment: It's always worth, in this sort of situation, just checking the value that `selected_int_kind(13)` returns.

Comment: Sorry, I'm very new. How would I do that?

Comment: I've updated my answer, see that short program that you can copy-paste, compile, and run.

Comment: Wait, is it possible that he needs to write `integer(kind=my_kind) :: num=600851475143_my_kind`?

Comment: Yes, that last one worked. Just so I have a greater knowledge of the language, why was that necessary, and is that always applicable?

Comment: I have completely re-written my answer, please check whether you're still happy with it.